# How do sort character frequency in descending order

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import sys
import string
from collections import Counter

input_char = str(sys.argv[1])

c = Counter(input_char.lower())

o = {k: c.get(k) for k in list(sorted(c.keys(),
                                      key=lambda key: (c.get(key)),
                                      reverse=True))[:5]}
print(o)
```

My input :

```
python CountPopularChar.py sdsERwweYxcxeewHJesddsdskjjkjrFGe21DS2145o9003gDDS
```

Current output:

```
{'s': 7, 'd': 7, 'e': 6, 'j': 4, 'w': 3}
```

Expected output:

```
{'d': 7, 's': 7, 'e': 6, 'j': 4, 'w': 3}
```

So how do I get the output in descending order of character frequency. And if the character have same frequency how do I get it to be printed in ascending ASCII order.

Comment: `lambda key: (c.get(key), key)`

Comment: `{k: v for _, g in groupby(c.most_common(5), itemgetter(1)) for k, v in sorted(g)}`. Imports: [`groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), [`itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

Answer (score 1):

You can sort by a tuple, of the value in the counter and the key itself, but with `reverse=True` this will give you the same result. So you need to sort only the value in reverse, which you can do by negating it:

```py
o = {k: c.get(k) for k in list(sorted(c.keys(),
                                      key=lambda key: (-c.get(key), key),
                                      ))[:5]}
```

Output:

```
{'d': 7, 's': 7, 'e': 6, 'j': 4, 'w': 3}
```

You can also use [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=most_common#collections.Counter.most_common) to avoid the slicing:

```py
o = {t[0] : t[1] for t in sorted(c.most_common(5),
                                 key=lambda t:(-t[1], t[0])
                                 )}
```

The output is the same.

Comment: Hi can I ask what does -c means

Comment: @theslasher that is negating the value returned by `c.get(key)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `most_common` for this:

```
string = "sdsERwweYxcxeewHJesddsdskjjkjrFGe21DS2145o9003gDDS"
c = Counter(string.lower())
dict(sorted(c.most_common(5), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]),reverse=True))
```

```
{'s': 7, 'd': 7, 'e': 6, 'j': 4, 'w': 3}
```